# How to install react beta types for typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, definitelytyped

As of now react 18 has entered beta state.
I used `npm install react@beta react-dom@beta` to install beta version and then used `npm install @types/react @types/react-dom --save-dev` to install the types. I am following this article https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-typescript-with-react-18-alpha/ except the part where it uses @next tag install react and react-dom. But when I checked inside node_modules/@types/react I cannot find `next.d.ts` file which was supposed to contain the updated definitions. Surprisingly I couldn't find a lot of information online about using typescript with latest react beta. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does `npm ls @types/react` show the 17.0.43 types?

Answer (score 0):

From the current head commit in the `DefinitelyTyped` repository:

[`@types/react/next.d.ts` lines 1–24](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/87fed5c5355e4518db03253847a1ce0cd40c05db/types/react/next.d.ts#L1-L24):

````
/**
 * These are types for things that are present in the upcoming React 18 release.
 *
 * Once React 18 is released they can just be moved to the main index file.
 *
 * To load the types declared here in an actual project, there are three ways. The easiest one,
 * if your `tsconfig.json` already has a `"types"` array in the `"compilerOptions"` section,
 * is to add `"react/next"` to the `"types"` array.
 *
 * Alternatively, a specific import syntax can to be used from a typescript file.
 * This module does not exist in reality, which is why the {} is important:
 *
 * ```ts
 * import {} from 'react/next'
 * ```
 *
 * It is also possible to include it through a triple-slash reference:
 *
 * ```ts
 * /// <reference types="react/next" />
 * ```
 *
 * Either the import or the reference only needs to appear once, anywhere in the project.
 */
````

Comment: I am aware of this, my question was about how to actually get the definitions (@types/react/next.d.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.
I managed to get the definitions when I installed `react` and `react-dom` with `next` tag.

```js
npm i react@next react-dom@next
```